# What makes an Android application vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: java, android, security, android-activity, sql-injection

**Definition of SQL Injection**

SQL injection is a code injection technique, used to attack data-driven applications, in which malicious SQL statements are inserted into an entry field for execution (e.g. to dump the database contents to the attacker).

**How SQL Injection impacts the Android O.S**

The SQLite used in android apps are fully functional databases, so just like SQL Server or MySQL box they can be susceptible to SQL injection. SQL injection typically works by adding data to the query string or adding data in a form field; to give hackers access to a database or unauthorized logins. SQL Injection is usually used to attack Web Views or a web service but it can also be used to attack Activities.

The root cause of the SQL Injection vulnerability is due to the use of dynamic or concatenated SQL queries. If SQL queries are constructed by concatenating user supplied inputs; The user can then supply SQL attack vectors instead of valid inputs and manipulate the backend SQL query.

The injection process works by prematurely terminating a text string and appending a new command. Because the inserted command may have additional strings appended to it before it is executed, the injected string is terminated with a comment mark “–”. Subsequent text is ignored at execution time.

**My Question**

Although I understand *what SQL Injection is* and *how SQL Injection can take place*. I don't know **what factors makes a selection of Android code vulnerable to such an attack.**

Comment: it takes place if you directly execute a query with user input without sanitizing it first. SQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name is " + mytextview.gettext.tostring())

Comment: [Same question on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/89897/539)

Comment: Please don't cross post. If you want different sites' perspective on the same problem then tailor your question to that site's audience. Which site do you want the question on?

Comment: I cannot delete it here, due to points and answers. But I'd like it posted to the Security One

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross post of [this post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89897/what-makes-an-android-application-vulnerable-to-sql-injection).

Answer (score 5):

SQL injection is not Android specific.

In any way the answer is simple: If you combine SQL command strings with user data input (via GUI, network, ...) the wrong way your application can get vulnerable to sql injection.

The simple sulution is to use only static SQL command strings in combination with [PreparedStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). All user data and other parameters are set on the PreparedStatement after it has been compiled.

Answer (score 3):

Well if your code takes variables like username and password and your app makes an sql query that just puts those variables into the sql string without sanatizing the strings first a user could inject bad code and the results could be bad. So just like with any app sanatizing user input is key to an attack being unsuccessful or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that what makes an Android application vulnerable to SQL Injection is a bad use or configuration of Content Providers in Android.

I wrote a blogpost about it recently, where I explain an example to inject SQL in Android content providers to obtain data and how to be protected against this kind of attacks, have a look at it: [link](https://solidgeargroup.com/sql-injection-in-content-providers-of-android-and-how-to-be-protected)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `<provider>` tag of the affected `ContentProvider` in your Manifest to set

```
android:exported="false"
```